# How to avoid infite updates in useEffect, when dependency is a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

A hook is checking, if there are impersonation information in storage persisted, when the page renders, and if so, sets those information in the global AppState context.

```
const impersonateStorageKey = `impersonation_${config.environment}`
// signature const impersonate: (empScope: number) => void
const { currentImpersonation, impersonate } = useAppContext()

useEffect(() => {
    if (!window || !window.localStorage) return;

    const storageString = localStorage.getItem(impersonateStorageKey)
    if (!storageString) return;

    const data = JSON.parse(storageString)
    impersonate(data.currentImpersonation)
}, [impersonateStorageKey])
```

With a second hook, that is persisting a change in the current impersonated identity to the storage:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!window || !window.localStorage) return;
    localStorage.setItem(impersonateStorageKey, JSON.stringify({ /* ... */}))
}, [currentImpersonation, impersonateStorageKey])
```

Plus the relevant bits from `useAppContext`

```
const useAppContext = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext)
    if (!state) {
        throw new Error("useAppContext must be used within within  AppContextProvider")
    }
  
    const impersonate = (employeeScope: string | number) => dispatch({ type: 'IMPERSONATE', value: employeeScope })
    const currentImpersonation = state.currentImpersonation

    return {
        impersonate,
        currentImpersonation,
    }
}
```

This is working as it should, but the linter is complaining, that the dependency impersonate is missing from the first useEffect hook

When I add `impersonate` to the dependency array, this will cause a constant update loop and make the application unresponsive.

I know what is causing this behaviour, but I am failing to see a solution (except ignoring the rule) on how to break the loop *and* make the linter happy.

What approaches can I take here?

Comment: Can, have and failed doing so. This too, causes a loop

Comment: It might be an array deps issue in `useCallback`. What were the dependencies of `impersonate` in the  `useCallback` you tried? Can you add the `useAppContext` relevant code sections plus the `useCallback` you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can memoize the function when you create it with [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback):

```
const useAppContext = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext)

  const impersonate = useCallback(
    (employeeScope: string | number) => dispatch({
      type: 'IMPERSONATE',
      value: employeeScope
    }), [dispatch])

  if (!state) {
    throw new Error("useAppContext must be used within within  AppContextProvider")
  }

  const currentImpersonation = state.currentImpersonation

  return {
    impersonate,
    currentImpersonation,
  }
}
```

If you can't, a workaround would be to put the function in a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). The `ref` is an immutable reference to an object, with the `current` property which is mutable. Since the `ref` itself is immutable, you can use it as a dependency without causing `useEffect` to activate (the linter knows it, and you don't even need to state it as a dependency). You can mutate `current` as much as you like.

```
const impersonateRef = useRef(impersonate)

useEffect(() => {
  impersonateRef.current = impersonate
}, [impersonate])

useEffect(() => {
  if (!window || !window.localStorage) return

  const storageString = localStorage.getItem(impersonateStorageKey)
  if (!storageString) return

  const data = JSON.parse(storageString)
  impersonateRef.current(data.currentImpersonation)
}, [impersonateStorageKey])
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the "better" option too and explain, what useRef actually does and why it solves my problem?

Comment: I'll be happy to, but I need the code of `useAppContext`. Edit the question to include it.

Comment: Done. I've omitted the irrelevant bits, to avoid noise.

Comment: Looks like workaround with refs because it can be solved with `useCallback`.

Comment: Wrapping impersonate in a useRef hook really does the trick. Let's see how long it takes to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @OriDrori move `useCallback` usage before `if` condition. Hooks can't be call conditionally.

Comment: oh, I tried memoizing it, in the component itself and it did not work. It never occured to me, that I can memoize it in the hook itself.

Comment: Good catch @PasVV. I miss my linter :)